# How to animate a opening lid?

Tags: animation, objects

How to rotate an object like a notebook lid? Using <kbd>R</kbd> does not rotate around the bottom of the object.

You can see the exact example [here](http://youtu.be/pDaLQtPIRd4).

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18085/2217 see my answer there.

Answer (score 1):

Position your cursor at the point you want your object to rotate around and snap the objects origin to the cursor.