# Rotate on a point?

Tags: animation, objects

I know... Origin to 3D cursor but it's not that Here's the start:
[image: object at start of animation]

Here's the end:
[image: object at end of animation]

And Here's the middle showing the problem:
[image: object in the middle of animation showing the problem]
Is there any way I can stop it from going off?

Comment: what is that you want to do? which pic is the right one?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16045/how-do-i-create-a-hinged-door

Comment: always apply transformations: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation/7307#7307

Comment: do you use an armature or an empty to control your animation? animated rotations can be tricky sometimes without bones or a parented object.

Answer (score 2):

**In Object Mode** select your object and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and **Apply Rotation & Scale**

In **Edit Mode** select the vertex where you want the object to rotate, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and select **Cursor to Selected**

Exit edit mode and do Transform->**Origin to 3D Cursor**.

[image]