# Make water wheel with hinges

Tags: animation, objects, rigging

Could I make little 'doors' in the water wheel that rotate with the wheel itself, but can also rotate around their own hinge?

[image: sketch of wheel and doors]

Comment: Ok, reduced to one question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First set up your doors with the origin on the hinge edge, or us an empty. See this question for more info [How do I create a hinged door?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/16045/2217)
Next [Parent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26109/2217) the little doors to the main water wheel.

[image: animated gif]
In the above gif I have added an empty that is also parented to the water wheel. That empty is used to control the rotation of all the doors with a *[Copy Rotation](http://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/transform/copy_rotation.html)* constraint on each of the doors.
[image: Copy Rotation constraint]