# How to rotate a mesh around another one?

Tags: mesh, transforms

I have a certain combat airplane model and i need to create all the animations to be able to use it in a game. I've got this:

[image: wireframe screenshot]

I need to rotate the elevator mesh (The one not selected) around the selected mesh. I've tried using the rotate tool but it always ends up moving the elevator mesh (rotating and translating around the center point/3d cursor) and that is not i want. I want the front of the mesh to go up and the back to go down, taking the little mesh as a pivot, so the mesh moves like an actual elevator would.

How should i go about this?

Comment: This sounds like a job for armatures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a guess you want to *select* the elevator mesh then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-*select* the pivot or controller mesh. With the elevator **selected** and the control mesh **selected** and **active** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> to parent the elevator to the pivot or control mesh. The first choice in the drop-down list should work: 'Object'.

However, do you need the pivot mesh? Perhaps you should use an empty object instead to control the rotation.

You can also move the center of rotation of an object. In edit mode select the front vertices of your elevator then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>U</kbd> to choose "Cursor to selected". <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of Edit mode back into Object mode and then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to bring up the Set Origin dialogue and press shortcut <kbd>T</kbd> to move "Origin to 3D Cursor".

An absolute must-read is Witold Jaworski's excellent reference work *Virtual Airplane* which can be found on his site:
[Virtual Aircraft](http://www.airplanes3d.net/index_e.html)

Here is a quick blend file showing one way to control a surface:
[controlled_elevator.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6y06t1scalsf6bl/controlled_elevator.blend?dl=0)

Under the Properties tag you can lock rotation in the x, y, or z axis:

[image: lock rotation]

Under the Constraints tab you can limit the rotation of the controller (the empty):

[image: limit rotation]

As a follow-up, and keeping within the aeronautical theme, here is a link to a blend file of a variable pitch propeller, controlled with bones and drivers:

[pitch_control_bones.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/btbv0bm9blyhoxq/pitch_control_bones.blend?dl=0)

[image: variable-pitch-propeller]

Comment: The attached blend is describing a possible solution quite nicely, i'll try to emulate it fitting my needs and report back

Comment: I did not use _exactly_ your method but something really similar. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16045/how-do-i-create-a-hinged-door. Given the similarities i will mark this answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. [Blender Cookie](https://cgcookie.com/blender/lessons/01-understanding-constraints/) may also be a good place to learn some useful tips.