# Animate the rotation of a shotgun barrel

Tags: animation, mesh, transforms

How can I rotate the barrel like so, in the first image below?
[image: desired mesh rotation]

I want the barrel to rotate 45° so that the shotgun shells can be put into the barrel. But when I rotate, I get this image below:
[image: mesh rotation problem]

[image: close up of barrels rotating incorrectly]

Comment: See if [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18085/2217) solves your problem.

Comment: You have 2 objects selected with different origins.  You probably want both objects to have the same origin so they rotate about the same point, or parent one object to the other and rotate just the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because the "Origin" of the barrel is all the way to the right of the screen. Every object has an "Origin" and it is the yellow dot that appears every time you select an object. 
Here is a tutorial to explain what an origin is and how to change it. - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FxrRdbk854

Comment: Thanks, however my rotation is not straight even though I am using R + X (45.0). My rotation curves to the right and falls in place with the desired 45 degree angle, that is straight from the new 3d cursor origin.

Comment: use [R + X + X]

Comment: I get the same result. I have to change it to R + Y + Y though.

Comment: oh ok. So, your problem is fixed now? or is it still now going straight?

Comment: No, though the rotation is perfectly straight over the x axis, the barrel is veering to the right as it makes its rotation. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you change the origin of the barrel?

Comment: Oh I see. The animation keyframes must be the problem. Change the last keyframe is probably the problem since the barrel might be veering to the right on that.

Comment: The objects have different rotation paths when I select them all and hit R + X + X

Is there a way I can combine all objects using join and still have the barrel pivot over the x axis?

Comment: If you join the meshes, you would be able to do what you want to do, but that is more complex as it would require "bones".

Comment: @nmm131 Try changing the view from Perspective to Ortho view by pressing the "5" key. You can switch from Front, Side and top views by pressing "1" "3" and "7" keys.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using bones, and only animate the rotation, then I would use the 3d cursor as your pivot point. [image]

Comment: well, it's a bit strange because he'd have to move the cursor back into location whenever he does this

Comment: When I play my animation from that originates from blender, the barrel animates backwards in the opposite direction. It still slides to the right then slides back to the left when making the 45 degree rotation animation though. I have tried all tricks above. It also rotates up instead of down.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is guessing your barrel was once the same object as the stock, and you separated them. If not, I'm sorry I could not be of a help.

When creating a object, an origin point is made in the center (usually) and if you were to go into **Edit mode** and work away, as you have, then at one point decide to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to separate the two objects (in this case, your barrel and the stock) later on in your model, then your separated object will have the same origin as the other.

Causing it to rotate at the wrong position.

I may of said that too confusingly, so I'll just say the solution now.

First, I created a very bad remake of your model, as it's currently 5:02 AM.

It took me 3 objects to spawn in, a cube, and 2 cylinders. I shift clicked the two cylinders and held <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to separate them into two objects.

At this point, I have what I believe is your current situation. To fix this, I selected the back faces of the barrel, and pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and set my 3D cursor to the median point of the selected faces. (*cursor to selected*) I then entered **Object mode** and pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and selected **Origin to 3D Cursor**

The barrel now rotates from there.

This is perhaps unhelpful, and I'm sorry if this is unclear or such. I shall add a gif tomorrow explaining the process. hope as someone could edit this for me, as I must sleep. Good luck in your efforts!

Comment: @Gwenn Centre is the british english way of spelling center. Was no need to edit it, IMO. :)