# How to open the lid on the laptop

Tags: modeling, animation

I am having issues with a laptop I converted from the sims 3 to the sims 4. The laptop in the sims 3 was animated, when a player clicks on the laptop, the lid opens when the sim goes to use the laptop.

The sims 4 does not have laptops, the game has desktops and pads. One other person was successful in getting the lid to open, but it stays open and never shuts. It is not animated.

I can either get the lid to open and stay open, or I can animate the lid.

I know nothing of animation and I do know it has to be outside of Blender.
So, I will need to open the lid and keep it open, but have neither "cut" through a mesh before. I am extremely new to Blender let alone to meshing and creating.

So, I would need detailed explanations; preferably with photos, I'm a visual learner.

Here is a photo of the laptop Here is the file [image]

[image: laptop full frontal view]

[image: semi top view of the laptop]

Thank you in advance for all of the help with this. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Never post you email out in the public, unless you want spam. Answers to questions posed at stack exchange stay at stack exchange where everyone can learn from them.

Comment: As long as you won the rights to the file you can always [upload it here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). Much better than having to email it.

Comment: Related: [How do I create a hinged door?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16045/how-do-i-create-a-hinged-door)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do.

1. In edit mode make sure you have the option to select faces.
2. Click random faces on the top and along the sides and corners, then Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then hit the <kbd>+</kbd> on keypad about 15-20 times to make sure you got the entire top lid selected.
3. Hit <kbd>P</kbd> to seperate the object, Position the top lid how you would like it to be open, follow the link ["how to create a hinged door"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16045/how-do-i-create-a-hinged-door) suggested in the above comments section.
4. Once the object is where you want it, select everything and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join it all back to one.

keep in mind nothing is modeled on the inside where the computer screen would be, so you would need to put something there

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.