# Hinged door by Copy Rotation: what if wall rotates?

Tags: constraints

I want to do wardrobe in Blender with hinged door. The simplest way to do it is by Copy Rotation constraint. On picture below, I have blue thing (wall) and red thing (door).
[image: Stationary wall]
Door has an origin at edge adjacent to wall and Copy Location constraint. Then I apply Copy Rotation constraint for X and Z axises, but not Y.
All as here: [How do I create a hinged door?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16045/how-do-i-create-a-hinged-door) .
And my door rotates along Y axis - when wall does not rotate.
But if I rotate wall along X axis - I have a problem:
[image: Rotated wall]
Door and wall intersects with each other!
How can I fix this?

[File can be downloaded here](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/gWT5FJwQk7dF0A)

Comment: for rotations that are not aligned with the global axis the best is to parent your doors to empties, tilt the empties the way you want and rotate the doors the way you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I have no idea what this setup should be. Why are wall and door lying down? And when you say "all as here" you link to a question where neither in the question nor in the answer is made use of *Copy Location* or *Copy Rotation* constraints - so in your example nothing is as it is there. Apart from that, you could simply parent the door to the wall (if it should be necessary because you are planning to arbitrary move and rotate the wall around a lot).

Anyway, to make this setup work as I guess you want it to, you simply have to enable all three axes for rotation and set the *Mix* to *Before Original* instead of the default *Replace*. After you change this, the door will follow the wall around no matter where you move or how you rotate it - and the wall's individual Y rotation can be used for "opening" or "closing" the door.

[image: copy rotation settings]

Comment: Thank you for your attention! Maybe I am not very well in explanations, but "Before Original" in "Mix" is really solution.

Comment: @АндрейГиль Yes, but selecting all axes is important, too - otherwise the door cannot follow the wall if you rotate it more freely.